# errors with fortran codes

Tags: fortran

i have multiple errors with this fortran code
tried many times to correct them but no clue
i hope someone can figure it out

[image]

```
Program mr
implicit none
logical::p,q,fun
read(*,*)p,q
print*,"------"
print*,"|p|q|p->q"
print*,"------"
print*,"|true|true|",function(true,true),"|"
print*,"------"
print,"|true|false|",fun(true,false),"|"
print*,"------"
print,"|false|true|",fun(false,true),"|"
print*,"------"
print,"|false|false|",fun(false,false),"|"
print*,"------"
end program mr
logical function fun(p,q)
logical::p,q
if(p==true .and. q==false)then
fun=false
else
fun=true
end if
end function
```

Comment: Your print statements about which the compiler is complaining are missing formats; compare with the print statements about which the compiler isn't complaing. `true` and `false` are not the same as `.true.` and `.false.`.

Comment: can you refer to the wrong code please

Comment: i mean what should i do

Comment: Never include error messages in a picture. They **must** be copied and pasted as **text**. It is extremely important. The title of your question also says nothing useful. The errors must be searcheable. See [ask].

Comment: @Ross I would even argue it is a disservice to include such pictures for the new users. They cannot include pictures themselves for good reasons.

Comment: Gratuitous comment: don't learn to write logical expressions like `if(p==true .and. q==false)` - not even when you have got the syntax right.  Instead prefer `if (p .and. .not. q)`.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Agreed about the image, I didn't add it - it looks like part of the original question to me. Whether I should have answered the low-quality question, meh - I couldn't find a good duplicate and the OP seems eager to learn.

Comment: @Ross Sorry, I thought it must have been added by you because you were the only editor. But it was indeed present in the original. I am quite sure it used to be impossible for completely new users to insert oňpictures directly not so long ago.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, there is nothing special about the variable `true` and `false`. They do not have pre-defined types or values. This misunderstanding is the cause of the error messages: the compiler says `Symbol 'true' does not have an implicit type`. (The `implicit none` statement at the beginning is good here, as it prevents you from other less-helpful errors.)

The defined logical parameters are instead `.true.` and `.false.`. Note the periods on either side. You should replace each instance of `true` with `.true.` and each instance of `false` with `.false.` After that, the compiler points out a few other errors for me:

- Missing a few `*` after `print`
- Switch `==` to `.eqv.` for comparing logicals
- Change `function` to `fun` in main body

There are some other improvements to make: put subroutines in a module, cleanup the logic in `fun`, and indent the code. But this should be enough to get you started. I am deliberately not pasting the final code here so you can make the changes yourself - good luck!

Comment: thanx i will try these fixes and let you know of results

Comment: i still get this error
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccKVLtGH.o: in function `MAIN__':
main.f95:(.text+0x21f): undefined reference to `function_'
/usr/bin/ld: main.f95:(.text+0x335): undefined reference to `function_'
/usr/bin/ld: main.f95:(.text+0x44b): undefined reference to `function_'
/usr/bin/ld: main.f95:(.text+0x561): undefined reference to `function_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: i figured it out just replaced function with fun and it worked as you mentioned before thanx again for your help